# Using Chosen how to post array of selected values back to controller as string

Tags: asp.net, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, http-post

Struggling with getting all the selected options in a Chosen select posted back to the model.

In View:

```
<select id="GridRegions" multiple name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.GridRegions)">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Centre">Centre</option>
    <option value="Inner">Inner</option>
    <option value="Outer">Outer</option>
</select>
```

In script block:

```
$("#GridRegions").chosen().change(function (e, params) {
    values = $("#GridRegions").chosen().val();
    $("#GridRegions").val(values);
    console.log("Grid: " + $('#GridRegions').val());
});
```

Console writes out the selected values correctly, e.g. Centre,Inner but only Centre gets passed back in the form post as the field expects a single string. I've followed numerous examples from SO on how to convert the array to a string within the script but it always errors in some way.

What is the best way to take the values array, turn it into a comma separated string and pass that to the model as the value of GridRegions? I'm using Entity Framework 6 so the GridRegions element is a part of the Grading model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Form(Grading grading)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Gradings.Add(grading);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a workaround to this, perhaps not the best solution but at least it's working for me and might help someone else. I ended up giving the select lists an alternative name and passing the data back to the action outside of the model as:

```
ICollection<string> Grids
```

Then in the action I converted the array to a string and assigned it to the model.

```
// stringify the multiselect arrays after check for null
if (Grids != null) 
{ 
    grading.GridRegions = String.Join(",", Grids); 
}
```

The only thing to be aware of is that you can't then do validation checks based on data annotations on these fields in the model since when the ModelState.IsValid check is carried out the actual model fields are NULL so additional checks have to be made within the action.

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax you could add a parameter to your controller action as an array of strings.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FooAction(string[] selectedValues )
{ 
    //do stuff
    return View();
}
```

First read the selected values into an object as follows:

```
var selectedValues = [];
$(".GridRegions :selected").each(function() {
  selectedValues.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Then send them as follows:

```
   $.post("/controller/FooAction", { selectedValues  : selectedValues  });
```

Comment: There are 14 Chosen select elements on this particular form, so I'd have to be passing back 14 different arrays as well as the rest of the model to the controller then I'd still have to convert them to a string there and add them to the model before saving. Would it not be better to do the conversion within the script block so that it can be passed back as part of the model?

Comment: @user3632714 Yes, you could add a model with the arrays as properties and then still use the above to send them. Let me know and I can update the question. Add you model to the question.